# How to turn a column in GridView to link

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, gridview, unhandled-exception

I'm using a GridView to display a report that shows information from different tables in a database. One column in this report is displaying checklistNo which is gotten from the maintenance table in the database. I am trying to make the checklistNo a link so when clicked it open the checklist page.

```
        protected void gvResults_OnItemDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
                    {
                        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                        {
                            lookupChecklist main = (lookupChecklist)e.Row.DataItem;
                            Maintenance maint = (Maintenance)e.Row.DataItem;
                            GridView gv = (GridView)sender;
                            Literal litChecklistNo = e.Row.FindControl("litChecklistNo") as Literal;

                            if (maint.ChecklistID.HasValue)
                            {
                                switch (maint.VehicleTrailer)
                                {
                                    case "Truck":
                                        {
                                            litChecklistNo.Text = "<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"OpenNew('/lookups/Vehicle.aspx?VehicleID=" + maint.LinkedID.ToString() + "&ChecklistNo=" + maint.CheckListNo + "', 'Vehicle');\">" + maint.CheckListNo + "</a>";
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    case "Trailer":
                                        {
                                            litChecklistNo.Text = "<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"OpenNew('/lookups/Trailer.aspx?TrailerID=" + maint.LinkedID.ToString() + "&ChecklistNo=" + maint.CheckListNo + "', 'Trailer');\">" + maint.CheckListNo + "</a>";
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    case "MSQ":
                                    default:
                                        {

                                            break;
                                        }
                                }
                            }
            }
```

Since the information I need is from the maintenance table I added `Maintenance maint = (Maintenance)e.Row.DataItem;` but that gives the error

> Unable to cast object of type 'BaseClasses.lookupChecklist' to type
>   'BaseClasses.Maintenance'.

Can I not call the maintenance class from another class?

```
public static List<lookupChecklist> SearchCheckListItems(int CompanyID,
                                                    string[] SearchTerms,
                                                    string[] SearchFieldKey,
                                                    string DateTypeKey,
                                                     int? ServiceTypeID,
                                                     DateTime? FromDate,
                                                     DateTime? ToDate,
                                                     string ResolveKey,
                                                     string MaintenanceKey
                                                               )
        {

            if (SearchTerms != null &&
                  SearchFieldKey != null &&
                  SearchTerms.Length > 0 &&
                  SearchFieldKey.Length > 0 &&
                  SearchTerms.Length != SearchFieldKey.Length)
                throw new Exception("Search Error: Search Terms must equal Search fields");

            List<MySqlParameter> param = new List<MySqlParameter>{ new MySqlParameter("compid", CompanyID) };
            StringBuilder SQL = new StringBuilder(SearchSQL);

            List<lookupChecklist> main = new List<lookupChecklist>();
            DataTable dtRes = lookupChecklist.CustomFill(SQL.ToString(), param);

            foreach (DataRow dr in dtRes.Rows)
            {
                main.Add(new lookupChecklist(dr));
            }

            return main;
}
```

Comment: Looks to me like you're binding lookupChecklists to the gridview and then trying to cast the bound object to the type 'Maintenance'...is that right?

Comment: @FullTimeSkeleton The gridview isn't binding to anything

Comment: What's the gridview's datasource? And how can it cast a row to type lookupChecklist  and then to type Maintenance?

Comment: @FullTimeSkeleton I added code for gridview in my question

Comment: I'm confused, when I've worked with Gridviews you provide them a datasource, then you can cast the rows to a type, once you know the source type. Given that, I've never seen a GV where there's an attempt to cast to two different types. If you remove this line: lookupChecklist main = (lookupChecklist)e.Row.DataItem; Does it work?

Comment: the same error comes up if I remove that line

Comment: I sitll don't see where your GV is being bound. Presumably you're binding it with items of type 'lookupChecklist'. Then you're attempting to cast those to the type 'Maintenance'  which is what is causing your error. You need to change the type or return a new class / anonymous type with the data you require and cast to that.

Comment: there's this line of code `gvResults.RowDataBound += new GridViewRowEventHandler(gvResults_OnItemDataBound);` is that how the gridview is bound?

Comment: No, you're probably looking for a datasource line somewhere. Something like gvResults.Datasource = ????

Comment: added the code to my question

Comment: Where did you get this code? I am not seeing a gridview binding anywhere unless I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: sorry you're right. please look at edit

Comment: There we go. You're binding the GV to a list of type lookupChecklist and then in the row databound you're attempting to say the equivalent of 'I don't want this item to be a lookupChecklist, i want it to be a 'Maintenance'....which the GV is objecting to.

Comment: ok so I can't call maintenance. Then back to my question - how do I create the link?

Comment: If there's no relationship between the two types then it not really going to work. By this I mean if your lookupChecklist and your Maintenance tables are not join-able via a common ID etc. then you can't query the Maintenance table from within the row databound as there's nothing to query on. What's their relationship do you know?

Comment: They are joined by ChecklistID `LEFT JOIN maintenance m1 ON m1.CheckListID `

Comment: Well then you've two options. First option is to bind the GV to a result set populated with the data from the joined tables. This is the cleanest and least DB intensive way. Second option is to query the DB on each databound row via the checklistID and then populate your links via the returned data. This is far more DB intensive though as you're querying it on each row as opposed to once at the start.

Comment: ok if I go with the first option what do I need to change in the bind code?

Comment: You need to change the query so that instead of returning a list of lookupChecklist items, it joins the Maintenance table and either returns a result set of some sort or you create a new class that combines the required fields of both tables and then return a list of that class.

Comment: Change this method SearchCheckListItems or create a new method that returns the data from the joined tables. Then you've access to your maintID and everyone is happy on earth.

Comment: what do I need to add to the SearchCheckListItems method to get the data from maintenance?

Comment: Well you need to edit that query (in LINQ or whatever you're using) so that instead of returning just a list of lookupChecklist it returns the required data from both tables. I'm guessing here as I don't know your query.

Comment: Added all the code for the SearchCheckListItems  method to the question

Comment: CustomFill is where your SQL lives I'd say.

Comment: ok I added `if (dr["CheckListID"] != DBNull.Value)
                    main.Last().mainItems.Add(new Maintenance(Convert.ToInt32(dr["CheckListID"])));` into the foreach  but I still get the same error unable to cast object

Comment: No, you need to get this at the query stage, select all the columns you need from both tables and then return the resultant data. Do not just return  lookupChecklist  items, you need a combination of both lookupChecklist  and Maintenance items. Create a new class, give it the properties you want to populate, do your query and populate a list of items of that new class type. Return than and bind to your GV...then you can cast on your databind to that new class and it'll have all your goodness in it.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for your data but creating a link...did you know that this:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <a id="SomeLinkId" runat="server" ></a>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Makes it available in the code behind where you can do something like this in the `RowDataBoundEvent`:

```
HtmlAnchor  anchor = e.Row.FindControl("SomeLinkId") as HtmlAnchor ;
```

Which makes link creation far easier and more readable

```
string FormatString = "";

if(maint.VehicleTrailer == "Truck")
  FormatString = "OpenNew('/lookups/Vehicle.aspx?VehicleID={0}&ChecklistNo={1}', 'Vehicle');";

else if(maint.VehicleTrailer == "Trailer" )
  FormatString = "OpenNew('/lookups/Trailer.aspx?TrailerID={0}&ChecklistNo={1}', 'Trailer');";

anchor.Attributes("href") = "#" ;
anchor.InnerText = maint.CheckListNo ;
anchor.Attributes("onclick") = string.Format(FormatString, 
                                             maint.LinkedID.ToString(),
                                             maint.CheckListNo );
```